# How to rewrite grep in #!/bin/sh?

Tags: shell, sh

I have the following shell script, that does not compile:

```
#!/bin/sh

.....
.....


clean_up() {
  echo "Clean up"
  docker stop $KC_TEST_SVC
  docker stop $KC_NAME
  docker stop $POSTGRES_NAME
  docker network rm $KC_NETWORK

}

# Check network if exists, if not then create
docker network inspect $KC_NETWORK
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  docker network create $KC_NETWORK
  if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    exit 1
  fi
fi

docker run -d --rm --name $POSTGRES_NAME \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=$POSTGRES_DB \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=$POSTGRES_USER \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PW \
  --network=$KC_NETWORK \
  postgres:12.3

if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  exit 1
fi

docker build --build-arg STAGE=int --tag $KC_TAG .
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  exit 1
fi

docker run -d --rm --name $KC_NAME \
  -e DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES \
  -e DB_ADDR=$POSTGRES_NAME \
  -e DB_DATABASE=$POSTGRES_DB \
  -e DB_USER=$POSTGRES_USER \
  -e DB_PASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PW \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=$KC_USER \
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=$KC_PW \
  -e KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG \
  --network=$KC_NETWORK \
  $KC_TAG "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/import-dir -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"

if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  exit 1
fi

# Wait until Keycloak get started
sleep 30

# Run test jetty service that is protected with Keycloak
docker run -d --rm --name $KC_TEST_SVC \
  -v $(pwd)/app:/app \
  --network $KC_NETWORK \
  hub.databaker.io/devops/jetty-keycloak:0.1.6
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  exit 1
fi

# Request Tokens for credentials
KC_URL=http://$KC_SERVER/$KC_CONTEXT/realms/$KC_REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token
echo "Keycloak URL => $KC_URL"

echo "Test the client connection to Keycloak with user $KC_TEST_USER"
KC_RESPONSE=$(
  docker run --rm --network=$KC_NETWORK curlimages/curl:7.71.1 -X POST \
    -d "username=$KC_TEST_USER" \
    -d "password=$KC_TEST_PW" \
    -d "grant_type=password" \
    -d "client_id=$KC_TEST_CLIENT" \
    $KC_URL | docker run --rm -i stedolan/jq .
)

echo "Response from Keycloak $KC_RESPONSE"

if grep -q "error" <<< "$KC_RESPONSE"; then
  echo "++++++++Error+++++++++"
  exit 1
fi

KC_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(echo "$KC_RESPONSE" | docker run --rm -i stedolan/jq -r .access_token)
echo "Access token from KC => $KC_ACCESS_TOKEN"

echo "Make request to protected service"
SVC_URL=http://$KC_TEST_SVC:8080/api/health
SVC_RES=$(docker run --rm --network=$KC_NETWORK curlimages/curl:7.71.1 -v -k \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $KC_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  $SVC_URL | docker run --rm -i stedolan/jq .status)

clean_up

echo "$SVC_RES"

if [ "$SVC_RES" != "I am healthy" ]; then
  echo "Test failed."
  exit 1
else
  echo "Test was successful. The service response $SVC_RES."
fi
```

it complains:

```
Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

due to of the following line:

```
if grep -q "error" <<< "$KC_RESPONSE"; then
  echo "++++++++Error+++++++++"
  exit 1
fi
```

`#!/bin/sh` does not support `grep`. How to rewrite it?

Comment: No, it is not about not having grep. And grep is independent of shell. It is just `<<<` which is not in your shell, and it is handled by your shell. `sh` is generic shell (see you first line), many systems uses a faster one. bash has many extensions, like `<<<`

Comment: just `echo "$KC_RESPONSE" | grep -q `? The error is because `<<<` herestring is a bash extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<<` is a here string and it's a bash extension. In posix shell, just pipe the data.

```
if printf "%s\n" "$KC_RESPONSE" | grep -q "error"; then
```

Do not do `if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then`, it's error prone. Do `if ! command; then`. (You might want to research `set -eu`).

Answer (score 0):

Change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` (ev. replace bash location, `which bash` helps to find location of bash, and to see if bash is installed), or you may need to rewrite your script in a portable way. In this case, create a temporary file, put the string in such file, redirect such file to grep (with single `<`), and then delete the temporary file.

With such long description, you see why there is an extension in bash, on the other hand, it is nearly a syntactic sugar: you can easily do the same.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker does not support bash

Comment: You can install it (as you did for jetty). I give you two solutions, one with and one without bash (KamilCuk solution works well, and it is optimal, but only for some cases). If you get often "bash errors" you should install it.